# PHP Arrays - How to use Variables inside?

Tags: php, arrays, string

i´ve got some Problems with the following code

```
function search_query_filter2($query) {
    if( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $test1 = 59602;
        $test2 = 33142;

        $plza = array($test1, $test2);

        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'colabs_zipcode' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', $plza);
        }
}
```

**First of all, this Code works in this way fine, now the Problem:**

As you see i set two variables in the following way:

```
        $test1 = 59602;
        $test2 = 33142;
```

to get them work in array() like:

```
        $plza = array($test1, $test2);
```

**______________________________________________________________________________________**

**BUT it should look like this to make it work for my requirements (String as Array variable)**

```
        $test = '59602,33140';
```

and

```
        $plza = array($test);
```

**I cant get it working =/**

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong and what needs to be fixed

Comment: The Problem is solved.

I need to use 

$plza = explode(",", $test);
instead of 
$plza = array($test);

for variables like

$test = '59602,33140';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$test = '59602,33140';
$plza = explode(",", $test);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PHP explode() function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

> Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

Your code would be similar to this:

```
$test = '59602,33140';
$plza = explode(',', $test);
```